# ModuleNotFoundError: No module names 'pddlstream'

Tags: python, ssh, drake, relative-import

So I know this question has been asked a **lot**, but I am seriously stuck and cannot work it out. Sorry, I am still learning relative imports.

So my file tree looks like this:
Work

[File tree, linux ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJ4aE.png)

In the run file of an example, I have this line:

```
from pddlstream.algorithms.meta import create_parser
```

and I'm getting back

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pddlstream'
```

I'm just confused since the file is definitely there. I've tried changing the main file name to be something different but originally it was just `pddlstream`.

Comment: It's not a relative import problem — the root module isn't being found.

Answer (score 0):

You should cd to the parent of the pddlstream[project] directory and from there issue:

```
$ python -m pddlstream[project].run
```

The -m switch will take care of the rest